# What is the SQL to select all the records from a table where the "LastName" is alphabetically between (and including) "Hansen" and "Peterson"?

Tags: sql

My current Statement is

```sql
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE LastName >’Hansen’ AND LastName <’Peterson’
```

is there a better way to do this?

Some people said

```sql
SELECT FROM Persons WHERE LastName BETWEEN ‘Hansen’ AND ‘Peterson’
```

is more correct

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: That is not "including" though.

Comment: Better meaning a more correct way, I'm unsure if this will workl

Comment: the two condition are not the same between mean => ...<=  (inclusive) while you first sample is > < (not inclusive)  ..  anyway  ..  you should define  what do you mean with "more correct way" ..  syntactically both are correct but semantically are different .. the produce twi different result

Comment: Define "more correct" (and don't say *"more correct meaning a better way"*)

Comment: If you use `>=` and `<=`, the two are equivalent.  Don't worry about which you use.

Comment: Alright thanks, I need to use the `<=` operators, or the between. Thanks!